# Best practice for passing SQL and retrieving/manipulating data using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

In my recent multi-user database application, there's a lot of retrieving and manipulating database data from different database source types (Oracle, Access, SQL Server). I know the .NET framework technologies to do this, and it basically works fine. But coding it the way I do seems tedious, and I'm looking for a better way. I'm relatively inexperienced in this, so I'm sure there is.

The way I'm doing it now is simply generating SQL Text Statements from parameters using string concatenation. I have also played with stored procedures in the main application database (Access), but it was too inflexible.

I'm very limited in what I can do. I cannot change Oracle and SQL Server databases. Alone the Access database that is owned by the application. The Oracle and SQL Server databases are quite slow, so I'm not sure if data binding is a good idea, as it would slow down the application (and user experience) each time data is queried. But again: I don't know much about data binding features.

Comment: Which DB providers are you using OLEDB or separate ones for each?

Comment: OleDb for Oracle and Access, Built-in .NET for SQL Server

Comment: I have downvoted because of a lack of clarity. Do you still need to work with Access as the main "hub" for your heterogeneous queries? Or are you asking for a way to eliminate Access using ADO.NET to speak to those disparate databases directly?

Comment: Also, how do you know that the Oracle and SQL Server databases are "slow" when you're communicating with them via Access, so that the slowness could be the result of the way Access sucks down immense amounts of data from the back-end into the client?

Comment: @Tim Access will store the static application data. Oracle and SQL Server in our backend stores dynamic data. I do not access those through Access, but directly with designated drivers/providers. I cannot change that in my part of the organization. I have a lot of constraints and need to get the best out of it given these, it will never be optimal. The backend databases are slow, as they are huge and not indexed properly for the purposes of my application, I cannot change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the back-end databases are not properly indexed, as you say in your comments, there's little you can do on the front-end to improve performance of the modules that pull data from the back-end, especially if those back-end databases are dynamic, changing frequently.

If you are allowed to write stored procedures on the back-end Oracle and SQL Server engines, you can improve performance *somewhat* by using SP's with parameters, and executing those SP's and passing the parameters via the Command object's Parameters collection.  This approach eliminates the overhead of your engines having to parse and compile SQL statements.

With respect to MS-Access, that too is a weak link.  Access is not a bona-fide back-end engine but uses a shared-file architecture.  Where-clause conditions are applied *client-side*, IIRC. So you end up sucking a lot of data across the wire only to discard it at the client because it does not meet the conditions of the where clause. You could improve performance by replacing Access with SQL Server Express, if your organization will have to use this application long enough into the future that the cost of such a port could be justified.

P.S. "Tedium" is subjective. I cannot help you there. Some people find ADO.NET tedious. Some people find Linq tedious. Some people are exhilirated by perl, others despise working with it.

Answer (score 1):

that being the case ... you can create a layer in which you access all the databases open close the active connection ... you can make your columns and value as `Dictionary` .... In this class expose methods where all you have to pass is db type , table name , `Dictionary` having col_name\value,query type (select/update/delete/insert/SP) ... For the `Dictionary` you could create models/entities/or even xml to the corresponding table, if you don't want them to be hard coded ..... But the Db layer class you will have to spend some time to make it as generic as possible ....

Comment: I have done something similar in a prior .NET application, that is work hard on generics, but even if it has worked flawlessly without errors, it was a lot of work and I ended up realizing that a less generic approach would have been both easier to read and required less work. Life of applications in my organization rarely have a life longer than 2 years, so one needs to consider cost-benefit carefully.